Did Socrates write verses before his execution?
Plato's Phaedo 60d to 61a is often translated as saying Socrates "wrote" some verses just before his execution.  Looking at the Greek, I think this is probably a correct translation.  But I would like to be more certain.
All the words translated as "write" are cognates of the Greek poiema.  This certainly can mean "write," but it can mean compose or create without writing.  Is there more direct evidence to show Plato indeed did mean "write"?

Given Socrates' circumstances facing imminent execution, there’s a practical implication that any poetic composition he completed was likely written down to ensure it could be shared or remembered after his death...

Did Nero fiddle while Rome burned?

@DoubleKnot That makes sense.  But nothing in the passages says the verses were, or would be, shared, even with the men he is talking with.  Socrates says he wrote in case that was the meaning of an ambiguous command he got in several dreams.

This question is better migrated to Latin Language which covers questions concerning the Ancient Greek language and texts.

@TankutBeygu The question is about Plato's philosophic intent, not about language.  The word clearly can mean write, but can also mean create.
